# Why is my iOS app not writing to the firestore emulator

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to setup a firebase emulator to simulate some actions in my iOS app. When I try to create a post to my emulated firestore I get the following error:

```
Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKitCore/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2020-12-10 17:55:48.513205-0500 Pikit[13139:100646] 6.25.0 - [Firebase/Firestore][I-FST000001] Listen for query at  failed: 
false for 'list' @ L6
Error Domain=FIRFirestoreErrorDomain Code=7 "
false for 'list' @ L6" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=
false for 'list' @ L6}
Error writing document: Error Domain=FIRFirestoreErrorDomain Code=7 "
false for 'create' @ L6" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=
false for 'create' @ L6}2020-12-10 17:55:48.545592-0500 Pikit[13139:100708] 6.25.0 - [Firebase/Firestore][I-FST000001] Write at posts/f1NriQ2UgIZ9HFOLyhgW7JzjLZw1/userPosts/2020-12-10 22:55:36 +0000 failed: 
false for 'create' @ L6
```

When I follow the same steps with my production database it runs as expected. Here is the code I use to specify the emulator settings:

```
private func emulatorSettings() {
        // [START fs_emulator_connect]
        let settings = Firestore.firestore().settings
        settings.host = "localhost:8080"
        settings.isPersistenceEnabled = false
        settings.isSSLEnabled = false
        Firestore.firestore().settings = settings
        // [END fs_emulator_connect]
    }
```

I call this function in my `viewDidLoad()` function of my `ViewController` like so:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
// called here
        emulatorSettings()
        tableView.reloadData()
        self.reloadInputViews()
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.register(UINib(nibName: K.cellNibName, bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: K.cellIdentifier)
        if let leftPostArray = userDefaults.array(forKey: fbLeftKey) as? [String]{
            votedLeftPosts = leftPostArray
        }
        if let rightPostArray = userDefaults.array(forKey: fbRightKey) as? [String]{
            votedRightPosts = rightPostArray
        }
        postQuery = Firestore.firestore()
            .collectionGroup("userPosts")
            .order(by: "postTime", descending: false)
            .limit(to: 4)
        
        loadMessages()
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know that this is an old post but I was struggling with the same issue and just fixed it.

I found that I was updating `Firestore.firestore().settings` too late in my app initialization process. I moved that code to right after calling `FirebaseApp.configure()` and it worked!

Firestore events are now showing up in my emulator.

Answer (score 2):

I found the problem that was preventing me from using the emulated firestore. The emulator does not follow the rules in the production level database but those stored locally in the firestore.rules file. to change the rules I renamed the file to firestore.rules.txt then edited them to allow all reads and writes.